# Discard millisecond part from timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, timestamp, rounding

How can I discard/round the `millisecond` part, better if the `second` part is also removed from a `timestamp` w/o `timezone` ?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

A cast to [`timestamp(0)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) or [`timestamptz(0)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) ***rounds*** to full seconds:

```
SELECT now()::timestamp(0);
```

Fractions are not stored in table columns of this type.

[`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) ***truncates*** (leaves seconds unchanged) - which is often what you really want:

```
SELECT date_trunc('second', now()::timestamp);
```

Comment: Note that timestamp(0) and timestamptz(0) will round rather than truncate.  Use date_trunc if you want to preserve the rest of the timestamp as is.

Comment: Doesn't work, it throws an error `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert`

Comment: @SlavikMeltser: The expressions in my answer work in Postgres. 100 %. Your problem obviously has a different cause.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I am using Amazon Redshift. Probably they have removed this feature in Redshift.

Comment: @SlavikMeltser: Redshift is not Postgres. It was forked from Postgres at version 8.0 - a *very* long time ago.

Comment: When I run `SELECT now()::timestamp(0);` in Datagrip (connecting to a postgres DB), it still shows the milliseconds, even though they are all zero.  I'd like to know how to remove that as well.  Might be a Datagrip setting I haven't found yet.  Interestingly, running `SELECT date_trunc('second', now()::timestamp);` does **not** show milliseconds.

Comment: @Purplejacket: Sounds like a matter of display in the sphere of Datagrip.

Comment: @Purplejacket I ran that exact query in Datagrip, and got it without milliseconds. FWIW I'm using Datagrip 2018.2 on Ubuntu 18.04, querying a PostgreSQL 9.5.15 server. I'm curious if either your Datagrip or postgres versions are older, and if an update of either/both has rectified your issue.

Answer (score 26):

**Discard milliseconds:**

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('second', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp);
```

> 2019-08-23 16:42:43

**Discard seconds:**

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('minute', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp);
```

> 2019-08-23 16:42:00

Answer (score 5):

if you just want time, here is the code for postgres

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('second', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp)::time;
```

it will return 'time without time zone' data type

Answer (score 1):

Try `select date_trunc('second',ur_date_field) as ur_date_field`.

It will return results like `2022-06-21 12:56:41`.