# Timestamp can't be saved as epoch number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, timestamp

I have the below code snippet:

```
class Foo    
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :timestamp, DateTime
 end
```

I just want to convert the current time to ms:

```
 class Time
   def to_ms
     (self.to_f * 1000.0).to_i
   end
 end
    
 def current_time
   time = Time.now
   return time.to_ms
  end

  time = current_time # => 1352633569151
```

But when I am going to save the Foo with above timestamp, then it can't be saved to the database and I'm not getting any error message.

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.timestamp = time
foo.save
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you get no error message, how are you determining that it "can't be saved"? Have you checked the PostgreSQL error logs? Enabled query logging and looked at the logs?

Comment: I could'nt find something related to this issue in `var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log` and `/var/log/syslog`. In general can we store timestamp in a DateTime field?

Answer (score 3):

are you using a correct format for your `:datetime` property?

should be like:

```
DateTime.now.to_s
=> "2012-11-11T14:04:02+02:00"
```

or a "native" DateTime object, without any conversions.

DataMapper will carry to convert it to according values based on adapter used.

also, to have exceptions raised when saving items:

```
DataMapper::Model.raise_on_save_failure = true
```

that's a global setting, i.e. all models will raise exceptions.

to make only some model to behave like this:

```
YourModel.raise_on_save_failure = true
```

http://datamapper.org/docs/create_and_destroy.html

See "Raising an exception when save fails" chapter

btw, to see what's wrong with your item before saving it, use and `item.valid?` and `item.errors`

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.timestamp = time
if foo.valid?
  foo.save
else
  p foo.errors
end
```

I replicated your code and got following error:

```
@errors={:timestamp=>["Timestamp must be of type DateTime"]}
```

### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=timestamp-cant-be-saved-postgresql.rb&run=true)

Answer (score 2):

The PostgreSQL data types would be [`timestamp` or `timestamptz`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). But that contradicts what you are doing. You take the epoch value and multiply by 1000. You'd have to save that as `bigint` or some [numeric type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html).

Basics:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

I would save the value as `timestamptz` as is. (No multiplication.) You can always extract ms if need should be.

If you need to translate the Unix epoch value back to a timestamp, use:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1352633569.151);
--> timestamptz 2012-11-11 12:32:49.151+01
```

#### Just save "now"

**If** you actually want to save "now", i.e. the current point in time, then let Postgres do it for you. Just make sure the database server has a reliable local time. (Maybe install [`ntp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) on the server.) This is generally more reliable, accurate and simple.

Set the [**`DEFAULT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) of the timestamp column to [`now()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) or [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).
If you want `timestamp` instead of `timestamptz` you can still use `now()`, which is translated to "local" time according to the servers timezone setting - effectively the same as `LOCALTIMESTAMP`. Or, to get the time for a given time zone:

```
now() AT ZIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna'  -- your time zone here
```

Or, in your particular case, since you seem to want only three fractional digits: `now()::timestamp(3)`, or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)`, or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) AT ZIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna'`, or `date_trunc('ms', LOCALTIMESTAMP)`. The latter *truncates*, while the other ones *round*. Typically, you want to truncate. See:

- [Discard millisecond part from timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213190/discard-millisecond-part-from-timestamp/10213289#10213289)

Or, if you define the type of the column as `timestamp(3)`, all timestamp values are coerced to the type and rounded to 3 fractional decimal digits automatically:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   -- other columns
, ts_column timestamp(3) DEFAULT now()
);
```

The value is set automatically on **`INSERT`**, you don't even have to mention the column.
If you want to do it **`ON UPDATE`**, add a [**`TRIGGER`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/triggers.html) like:

Trigger function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_up_ts()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.ts_column := now();
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$
```

Trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER log_up_ts
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_up_ts();
```

In Postgres 10 or older use the key word `PROCEDURE` instead of `FUNCTION`. See:

- [Trigger uses a procedure or a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307500/3684)

Now, everything works automatically.

Comment: As you see in my post I am using postgresql via DataMapper, when I set the time as Timestamp, then rails complain about the type?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL, but why are you assigning a Fixnum (`time`) to `timestamp` (which is a DateTime)? Your model must be failing to convert `time` to a proper DateTime value before generating the SQL.

Try `foo.save!`. I'm pretty sure you'll see an error, either reported from PostgreSQL, saying `1352633569151` is not a valid value for the table column, or your model will say it can't parse `1352633569151` to a valid DateTime.

`foo.timestamp = Time.now` or `foo.timestamp = '2012-11-11 00:00:00'` is something that'll work.