# Populate a Postgres table with old values from a function (not a trigger)

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, concurrency, plpgsql

I have a function that updates a unique column `mytable.value` from `oldvalue` to `newvalue`.

The problem is that I'd like to store `oldvalue` along with the old `modified` time in a separate archive table.

I don't know how to do this using a plain `plpgsql` function (Postgres 9.6). I think I know how to do it using a trigger, but I want the archive table to be populated only in certain cases, so when the function is explicitly called, rather than every modification to `mytable`.

```
create or replace function updatevalue(oldvalue text, newvalue text) returns void
  language plpgsql
  as $$
begin
  update mytable set modified = now(), value = newvalue where value = oldvalue
end
$$;
```

How can I modify the above function to populate the archive table with the old `modified` time? I don't want to pass it from the application as an argument to the function because of possible race conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning **"possible race conditions"**:
If you run separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements for this you get exactly what you wanted to avoid: a race condition. Anything can happen to the old row between `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, it has not been locked.

Enclosing both in a transaction (like the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823516/939860) suggests) does *not* fix this. You could lock the row(s) with `FOR UPDATE`, or access row(s) only once with a data-modifying CTE:

```
WITH upd AS (
   UPDATE mytable n
   SET    modified = now()      -- consider a trigger instead
        , value = $newvalue     -- provide value once
   FROM   mytable o
   WHERE  o.value = $oldvalue   -- provide value once
   AND    n.value = o.value
   RETURNING o.*                -- returns pre-update row
   )
INSERT INTO archive
SELECT * FROM upd;
```

Row(s) in `mytable` are only accessed *once*. No race condition and a bit faster, too. Related:

- [Return pre-UPDATE Column Values Using SQL Only - PostgreSQL Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only-postgresql-version/7927957#7927957)
- [Lock for SELECT so another process doesn't get old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357105/lock-for-select-so-another-process-doesnt-get-old-data/29359520#29359520)

This is assuming identical structure for `mytable` and `archive`, so I omitted the  target column list from the `INSERT`. If the structure is not identical or can change, be explicit and spell out columns instead.

You can wrap it into a (plpgsql or sql) function or execute it directly (as prepared statement).

Aside: Instead of setting `modified` manually, I would consider a trigger `ON UPDATE` or `ON INSERT OR UPDATE` taking care of this automatically:

- [Timestamp can't be saved - postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330835/timestamp-cant-be-saved-postgresql/13330967#13330967)

#### Alternative: explicit locking with `FOR UPDATE`

```
BEGIN;  -- one transaction

INSERT INTO archive
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  value = $oldvalue
FOR    UPDATE;            -- lock !

UPDATE mytable
SET    modified = now()
     , value = $newvalue
WHERE  value = $oldvalue;

COMMIT;
```

If you wrap this in a function, it's one transaction automatically.

Related:

- [Optimizing concurrent updates in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/optimizing-concurrent-updates-in-postgres/68398#68398)
- [Lock for SELECT so another process doesn't get old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357105/lock-for-select-so-another-process-doesnt-get-old-data/29359520#29359520)

Comment: You are correct, I really missed lock rows in my answer. Also very nice solution for returning pre-update values

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'll be using your CTE solution but would you mind also posting the `FOR UPDATE` option you mentioned? I'm curious for my own learning how that would look like. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is very simple, if I understand your question correctly.

So, if you want archive every old value and its modified time at update/function call, then you just need `archive_table` with structure:

```
mytable_pk_value int/bigint -- assumes that mytable have primary key/identity column, lets say "id"
mytable_modified_time -- with  mytable.modified datatype
mytable_oldvalue      -- with  mytable.value datatype
```

Then in function you have:

```
...
begin
  insert into archive_table 
  (mytable_pk_value, mytable_modified_time, mytable_oldvalue) 
  select id, modified, value 
  from mytable 
  where value = oldvalue;
  update mytable set modified = now(), value = newvalue where value = oldvalue
end
...
```

Comment: While the time frame for possible race conditions is short this way (no round trip to client and back), the race condition is still there. The transaction wrapper does not fix it. And values have to be provided twice.

Comment: I'll mark @ErwinBrandstetter's answer as accepted since it addresses the possible race conditions aspect. Thanks for your answer it got me started quickly and I really appreciate it.