# Ignoring seconds from timestamp postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am running a cron job every 1 minute for notifying users for events

```
select * from events where event_start = now()  - interval '30 minutes'
```

so that I can send the users a notification prior to 30 mins of event

problem is event start is a timestamp field so if there is a difference in seconds it this wll not work ,so how can ignore the seconds part .

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213190/discard-millisecond-part-from-timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc()` to remove the seconds:

```
select * 
from events 
where event_start = date_trunc('second', now())  - interval '30' minutes
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Answer (score 0):

In order to ignore seconds, you can use [date_trunc()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function.

> The function date_trunc is conceptually similar to the trunc function
> for numbers.
>
> date_trunc(field, source [, time_zone ]) source is a value expression
> of type timestamp, timestamp with time zone, or interval. (Values of
> type date and time are cast automatically to timestamp or interval,
> respectively.) field selects to which precision to truncate the input
> value. The return value is likewise of type timestamp, timestamp with
> time zone, or interval, and it has all fields that are less
> significant than the selected one set to zero (or one, for day and
> month).
>
> Valid values for field are:
>
> - microseconds
> - milliseconds
> - second
> - minute
> - hour
> - day
> - week
> - month
> - quarter
> - year
> - decade
> - century
> - millennium

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 2001-02-16 20:00:00

SELECT date_trunc('year', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 2001-01-01 00:00:00

SELECT date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40+00');
Result: 2001-02-16 00:00:00-05

SELECT date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40+00', 'Australia/Sydney');
Result: 2001-02-16 08:00:00-05

SELECT date_trunc('hour', INTERVAL '3 days 02:47:33');
Result: 3 days 02:00:00
```

So in your case, you should use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events
WHERE event_start = date_trunc('minute', now()) - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE;
```