# Select records with unique created_at value in rails postgres

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, uniq

The timestamp has milliseconds, so if any records are created via automation they will likely have the same seconds value but different millisecond values.  I need to do this:

Version.uniq(:created_at)

But, this doesn't work because they are all unique.  How can I use to_i, or whatever else might work, to pull this off?

Comment: I've created at class method called created_at_int.  Then I tried a query like this: Version.all.uniq(:created_at_int).  It did not error...but it did not return the expected results.  As a matter of fact...I could type literally anything as the symbol and get the same result.

Comment: Try giving `Version.uniq(:created_at).to_time`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) PostgreSQL function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('second', created_at) FROM "version"
```

In ruby:

```
Version.select("date_trunc('second', created_at)").distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

To just get rid of fractional seconds, cast to the equivalent type with 0 fractional digits.

```
SELECT DISTINCT created_at::timestamp(0) FROM "version"
```

Or [`timestamptz`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html), you did not disclose your exact type.
For more specific needs use [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).
More details:
[Discard millisecond part from timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213190/discard-millisecond-part-from-timestamp/10213289#10213289)

Comment: @hellion: I am no Ruby export, but it's just a simple cast (like any other expression). Maybe you need SQL standard notation: `cast(created_at AS timestamp(0))` ...