# postgresql - NOW() but less specific

Tags: postgresql

When I use SELECT NOW(); I'll get an output like this:

```
          now              
-------------------------------
2019-09-09 18:55:38.794006-05
(1 row)
```

I want it like this:

```
          now              
-------------------
2019-09-09 18:55:38
(1 row)
```

How do I make NOW() round up/down accordingly? I tried SELECT NOW()::timestamptz(0); but it keeps adding -05 to the end of the time :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discard millisecond part from timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213190/discard-millisecond-part-from-timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert NOW() to a [timestamp without timezone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

```
SELECT NOW()::timestamp(0)
```

Comment: Gives me: 2019-09-09 19:14:45.064555

Answer (score 3):

You can `to_char`

```
select to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

or use `date_truc` to retain datatype `timestamp with time zone`

```
select date_trunc('minute', now());
```

Comment: Looks like it works nicely, but trying to add that to a TIMESTAMP column gives me: ERROR:  column "date_of_receipt" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text

Comment: J Spratt - My field is TIMESTAMP not timestamptz