# Time difference between two timestamps in postgres using age is not rounding up

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp, date-difference

Trying to determine the time difference between two timestamp fields in postgres in `HH24:MI:SS` format, i.e.

```
date_started and date_completed
```

that have the following data:

```
date_started = 12/11/2021 09:11:00
date_completed = 12/11/2021 09:19:00
```

Using the following query:

```
select to_char(AGE(date_completed, date_started),'hh24:mi:ss') as "time_diff"
from my_table
```

returns the following value: `00:07:59`

Notes: both these fields have a data type of: `timestamp without timezone`

My question is, why is this not actually returning `00:08:00` seeing that it is exactly, 8 minutes difference?

Comment: What is the datatype of the date columns? Particularly, do they have fractions of seconds? Try `select to_char(date_started, 'hh24:mi:ss.us'), to_char(date_completed, 'hh24:mi:ss.us')` to see their microseconds part.

Comment: This works for me on v14, FYI. `select to_char(age('2021-12-11 09:19:00', '2021-12-11 09:11:00'),'hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: Updated question to include data types - `timestamp without timezone`

Comment: 1) Why not just do: `select '12/11/2021 09:19:00'::timestamp - '12/11/2021 09:11:00'::timestamp ; 00:08:00`? 2) Where are you seeing the values `12/11/2021 09:11:00` and `12/11/2021 09:19:00`? Are  you sure they are not being rounded by the client? In `psql` do a `SELECT` for the fields and see what is actually being stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue using the following:

```
select to_char(AGE(DATE_TRUNC('second', date_completed::timestamp), DATE_TRUNC('second', date_started::timestamp)),'hh24:mi:ss') as "time_diff"
from my_table
```

Reference SO: [Discard milliseconds part from timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213190/discard-millisecond-part-from-timestamp)

Just want to also acknowledge @Bohemian for their input in assisting me to solve this issue wrt microseconds.

Comment: So your data where not `12/11/2021 09:11:00` and `12/11/2021 09:19:00`.  That would have been a useful piece of information to convey in your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - apparently not but at the time of posting my question, I wasn't aware of the microseconds component which `Bohemian` pointed me in the right direction.