# How to convert YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ timestamp to YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp

**Problem Summary**

I would like to convert and validate the timestamp which is in YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ format (ex: 2022-06-15T08:27:00.599Z) in postgres.

**I tried**

```
select * from my_table WHERE my_date >= date_trunc('second', '2022-06-15T08:27:00.599Z'::timestamp)

select to_char(to_timestamp('2022-06-15T08:27:00.599Z','YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

These queries are executing fine in db_fiddle but giving an errors while running in python and postgres SQL.

**Facing errors**

> RROR: TEIID31100 Parsing error: Encountered
> "'2022-06-15T08:27:00.599Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS),
> '[*]YYYY[*]-MM" at line 1, column 672.Was expecting: "and" | "between"
> | "in" | "is" | "like" | "like_regex" | "not" | "or" | "order" |
> "similar" ...org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidSQLException: TEIID31100 Parsing
> error: Encountered
> "'2022-06-15T08:27:00.599Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS),
> '[*]YYYY[*]-MM" at line 1, column 672.Was expecting: "and" | "between"
> | "in" | "is" | "like" | "like_regex" | "not" | "or" | "order" |
> "similar" ...;Error while executing the query nil

**My need**

> *Input timestamp : 2022-06-15**T**08:27:00.599**Z**
>
> Expected timestamp : 2022-06-15 08:27:00*

Appreciate your support.

Comment: Remove the `\ ` it has no meaning in SQL. `to_timestamp('2022-06-15T08:27:00.599Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')` works just fine.

Comment: Here is the issue, I just ran my query. ERROR: TEIID30068 The function 'to_timestamp('2022-06-15T13:03:00.003Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')' is an unknown form.  Check that the function name and number of arguments is correct.org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidSQLException: TEIID30068 The function 'to_timestamp('2022-06-15T13:03:00.003Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')' is an unknown form.  Check that the function name and number of arguments is correct.;Error while executing the query nil

Comment: That's not a Postgres error message. My syntax [works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f54a55d3ec3f8657f06cb2ec3aee53bc) with Postgres. Which DBMS are you really usign? `select version();`   should tell you.

Comment: version :  `Teiid 8.7.13.6_2-redhat-1`.  pg server info: `options': '', 'sslmode': 'prefer', 'sslcompression': '0', 'sslsni': '1', 'ssl_min_protocol_version': 'TLSv1.2', 'gssencmode': 'disable', 'krbsrvname': 'postgres', 'target_session_attrs': 'any'}`

Comment: That's definitely not the output of Postgres' `version();` function.

Comment: @rajS this is not the postgres version. Perhaps from the client?

Comment: got it. Let me redirect it to TEIID group.

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name ,Jim Jones, Thanks a lot for your finding. It is issue with SQL supported functions of TEIID. Not postgres. I found the wat to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me if I am oversimplifying your question, but wouldn't a simple cast and `date_trunc` do the trick?

```
SELECT date_trunc('second','2022-06-15T08:27:00.599Z'::timestamp);

     date_trunc      
---------------------
 2022-06-15 08:27:00
```

An alternative is to round the seconds with `::timestamp(0)` - see this other [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213289/2275388). But it would return a different result:

```
SELECT '2022-06-15T08:27:00.599Z'::timestamp(0);

      timestamp      
---------------------
 2022-06-15 08:27:01
```

Comment: Any other tips ?

Comment: @rajS perhaps after you tell us what is wrong with those posted here :-D keep in mind that `TEIID30068` isn't a postgres error code. The problem seems to be in the client itself

Comment: it is actually VDB. I was successfully accessed the vdb using sql queries initially. when I am converting and validating now I am facing the issues like this.

Comment: @rajS I honestly never even heard of VDB. These queries posted here work just fine on postgres, so your problem seems to be somewhere else.